# Sharing cookies/session from WebView to HttpClient doesn't work

Tags: android, cookies, webview, httpclient, share

I know this question has been asked a hundred times, and I've read and tried for 2 hours now, but I can't find my error :-(

I am trying to create a simple webbrowser and therefore have a webview, where I login on a site and get access to a picture area. With help of a DefaultHttpClient, I want to make it possible to download pictures in the secured area.
Therefore I am trying to share the cookies from the webview and pass them on to the HttpClient, so that it is authenticated and able to download. But whatever I try and do, I always get a 403 response back...

Basically the steps are the following:

1) Enter URL, webview loads website

2) Enter login details in a form

3) Navigate to picture and long hold for context menu

4) Retrieve the image URL and pass it on to AsynTask for downloading

Here's the code of the AsyncTask with the Cookie stuff:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

//params[0] is the URL of the image

            try
            {

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

                String c = cookieManager.getCookie(new URL(params[0]).getHost());               

                BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
                BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
                String[] cookieParts = null; 
                String cookies[] = null;

                cookies = c.split(";");

                for(int i=0;i<cookies.length;i++)
                {                   
                    cookieParts = cookies[i].split("=");
                    BasicClientCookie sessionCookie = new BasicClientCookie(cookieParts[0].trim(), cookieParts[1].trim());
                    sessionCookie.setDomain(new URL(params[0]).getHost());

                    cookieStore.addCookie(sessionCookie);                   
                }


                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

                HttpGet pageGet = new HttpGet(new URL(params[0]).toURI());


                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(pageGet, localContext);
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
```

--> NEVER Happens, always get 403

.)  One of the problems is that the webview saves some cookies for the host **www.**example.com, but the image-URL to download (params[0]) is **static.**example.com. The line 
`cookieManager.getCookie(new URL(params[0]).getHost());` 
returns null, because there is no cookie for static.example.com, but only for www.example.com.

.) When I manually say cookieManager.getCookie("www.example.com"); I get some cookies back, which I add to the HttpClient cookie store: 
There are 5 cookies added
- testcookie = 0
- PHPSESSID = 320947238someGibberishSessionId
- email = my@email.net
- pass = 32423te32someEncodedPassGibberish
- user = 345542

So although these cookies, a session ID and other stuff, get added to the HttpClient, it never get's through to download an image. Im totally lost... though I guess that it either has something to do with the cookies domains, or that Im still missing other cookies.

But from where the heck should I know which cookies exist in the webview, when I have to specify a specific URL to get a cookie back?? :-(

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I guess we have made it too complicated in above snippet. 
Use these easy steps -

1)**Retrieve the cookie from webView** -wherever your webview is, use this code to re

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(
                        url.toString());
                Log.d("mytcs", "cookie downloadlistner " + cookie);
```

2) **Pass this in your downloading asyncTask using params** -

```
downloadImageTask = new DownloadImage();
                    downloadPDFTask.execute(url, cookie);
```

(I assume you know to retrieve this cookie in asyncTask, you will use params[**1**],

3) **set this cookie in your http request using** -

```
if (cookie != null)
    con.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookie);
```

where con is `HttpURLConnection con;`

so you can set it to your need, in `HttpGet`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured out the answer already coz it is a pretty late answer. But, just in case...

Try this. When you retrieve the cookie from WebView just use `example.com` in the domain name. When you set the cookie in `BasicClientCookie` and set the domain, set the domain name to `.example.com`. Note the "." in the beginning. Now, i think the session should work across all subdomains in your application.